# convolution of nearly periodic data

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose I have two vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$. I am interested in efficient calculation of the convolution
$$z(k) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x(i)y(i+k)$$
for $k=0,...,n-1$. Note that $y$ is taken nearly periodic i.e. $y(n+i)=\alpha y(i)$. For the simple case $\alpha=1$, this can be calculated efficiently using a Fourier-Transform as $x*y=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(x)\mathcal{F}(y))$. Is there a generalization of this method to other values of $\alpha$?

(If general $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$  are too tricky, pure phase factors, i.e. $\alpha=e^{i\phi}$ are probably enough for my usecase)

Comment: How could a $n$-dimensional vector $y$ have component $y(n+i)$?

Comment: I have only $n$ independant numbers, but it is considered to be an infinite periodic signal.

Comment: Is only $y$ quasi-periodic, and $x$ properly periodic? And do you want the correlation (as suggested by your formula) or the convolution (as you write in the text)? The convolution has $x(i)y(k-i)$.

Comment: As it is written, $x$ is only used in the range $[0,n)$, and $y$ is quasi-periodic.Though You are right, I should have called it "correlation". (Though in the $\alpha=1$ case, that can easily be written as a convolution by reversing $y$).

Comment: I think the proper generalization would be to take $x$ quasi-periodic with constant $\beta$, which would result in $z$ being quasi-periodic with constant $\alpha\beta$.